# Linear Gradient CSS Not Working in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a linear gradient css style for a button and for some reason it's not working. I think it may be a react issue, not really sure.

Code:

```
import React from "react";

var bg = {
  background: "#FFFFFF"
}

var btnFill = {
  background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4)'
}


class ConsolePage extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div style={bg}>
      <div class="uk-sticky-placeholder"></div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1">
          <div className="uk-grid">
            <div className="uk-margin-left uk-margin-top uk-margin-bottom uk-width-1-3@m">
              <div className="uk-margin-xlarge-top">
                    <div className="my-3" align="center">
                    <h3 className="mb-1">placeholder text</h3>
                        <div className="uk-grid">
                          <div>
                            <button href="/docs">
                              Learn More
                              <div className="btn"></div>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <button href="/tracker/nwa/lab/add">
                              Let's get started!
                              <div className="" style={btnFill}></div>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>


          </div>

              </div>
      </div>
  }
}

export default ConsolePage;
```

It just renders as a button that has no styles to it. If I leave out the `'`'s like so:

```
var btnFill = {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4)
}
```

react says this: `Unexpected token, expected ","` between `to right`.

Regards

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59278560/6544460 that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's working

```
const mystyle={
  background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #430089, #82ffa1)'
}
```

---

```
<div style={mystyle}>
    Linear Gradient
</div>
```

It seems you have not used text or something inside your div to which you are applying styling.

Comment: -_-, totally looked over the div without anything there... Thanks this works!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `div` inside a `button`, but you can put an image.

`<img src="...." />`

Or instead of a `button`, you can use a link

```
const btnFill = {
  backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4)';
}
<a style={btnFill} href="/tracker/nwa/lab/add">Let's get started!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I removed the div from the button and applied the style directly to the button itself.